# I need to increase the number of records displayed in the Bestsellers report

Tags: reports

I am told I need to do this by going to `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php`  however I am not sure how to get there.  Am I to assume that I begin with the site URL say `XXXXX.co.uk/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php`  If so I am told the page is forbidden.  Can yo help this newbie  ...please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish an FTP/SFTP or SSH connection with your server and navigate to the file location at 
`magento root/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php`

Note that "magento root" is where your magento instance is installed.